# Switch Ajax Tabs in TabContainer by Tab ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ajax control toolkit `TabContainer`. The active tab is controlled using c# in the following manner below. I have many tabs on my tabcontainer.

Is it possible to switch tabs by referencing the tab ID in C# as opposed to the number of the tab?

**c#**

```
TabContainerMain.ActiveTabIndex = 5;
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainerMain" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="4" Width="100%"
    Height="100%" CssClass="" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Tab_Monitor" ID="Tab_Monitor">
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel ID="Tab_Remove_Item" runat="server" HeaderText="Tab_Remove_Item">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="TabControls">
                <p>
                    Howdy, I'm in Section Tab_Remove_Item .</p>
            </div>
            <div class="TabsAction">
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel ID="Tab_2nd_Sign_System" runat="server" HeaderText="Tab_2nd_Sign_System">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="TabControls">
                <p>
                    Howdy, I'm in Section Tab_2nd_Sign_System .</p>
            </div>
            <div class="TabsAction">
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel ID="Tab_Configure_Device" runat="server" HeaderText="Tab_Configure_Device">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="TabControls">
                <p>
                    Howdy, I'm in Section Tab_Configure_Device .</p>
            </div>
            <div class="TabsAction">
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `ActiveTab` property. For example:

get

```
if(TabContainerMain.ActiveTab == this.Tab_Remove_Item)
{
    // ...
}
```

set

```
TabContainerMain.ActiveTab = this.Tab_2nd_Sign_System;
```

If you only have the ID as string, you can use LINQ (or a loop) to get the reference:

```
String tabPanelID = "Tab_Remove_Item";
TabContainerMain.ActiveTab = TabContainerMain.Tabs
    .Cast<AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel>()
    .First(t => t.ID == tabPanelID);
```